# how to run my application above keyboard when user click on any textView in any application?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I would like to visible my application view above the keyboard whenever the user clicks on textView in any application, the only thing that I knew is my application should be running in background and make the view visible when keyboard gets called, but I'm not sure if that's possible and if it's, I don't know how to do that.

I hope that helps you to get what I'm talking about
[image]

**Edit 8/5/2016:**
I create a foreground service but I don't know how to detect soft keyboard in the other apps

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent SERVICE_INTENT = new Intent(this,MyServiceTest.class);
        startService(SERVICE_INTENT);
    }
}
```

MyServiceTest.java

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;


public class MyServiceTest extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Intent MAIN_INTENT = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,MAIN_INTENT,0);
        Notification myNotification = new Notification.Builder(this).setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText("The Content text").setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setContentIntent(myPendingIntent)
                .build();
        startForeground(1337,myNotification);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            }
        });
        myThread.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".MyServiceTest">
        </service>
    </application>
```

Any information or idea could be helpful, Thanks in advance ^_^

Comment: I don't think you can add a strip above any soft keyboard mainly because they are also apps that have their own views.

Comment: So, the only solution is to create my own app keyboard ?!

Comment: Yes, that seems to be your only option here.

Comment: unfortunately :/ anyways, thanks for helping me ^_^

Comment: Add permanent overlay (system alert /overlay / phone) which is transparent and not touchable. Align it to the bottom of the screen. Record the position. Make it visible once the position of your layout changes the y axis. (expl.: keyboard will push your views upwards)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:
`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"`

Add it to your activity in your manifest.

Example:

```
<activity
        android:name="activities.WorkObjectActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"//This one
        android:label="@string/urenToevoegen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:parentActivityName="activities.MainActivity"/>
```

Comment: Is this what you needed?

Comment: could you explain it more and give me a simple example, because I'm new in android development

Comment: it's still not working, I edit my question please take a look if something is missing

Comment: @RobinDijkhof He wants to run his activity on top of other apps and above the keyboard. This doesn't work if the keyboard is triggered for another app.